# NoMethodError when method is defined in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class PalCheck
  palindromes = [
    "aba",
    "abc"
  ]
  def palindrome?(string)
    string = string.downcase.scan(/\w/)
    string == string.reverse
  end
  palindromes.palindrome?
end
```

I keep getting a NoMethodError, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use it like:

```
palindromes.palindrome?
```

define it like:

```
class Array
  def palindrome?
    string = self.downcase.scan(/\w/)
    string == string.reverse
  end
end
```

or omit `self` in it like:

```
class Array
  def palindrome?
    string = downcase.scan(/\w/)
    string == string.reverse
  end
end
```

although you get probably get a different no method error, because `Array#downcase` is not defined in standard Ruby setup.